# How to save Array in View State? And Retrieve That in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I am using Asp.Net With JqueryMobile (C#). I declare  string[] roomno = new string[100]; in my Class.

In **Page_load Event**:-

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    Some Code...
     for (int j = 0; j <= vallen; j++)
     {
         roomno[j] = "A" + Convert.ToString(j + 1);
     }
    Some Code,..
}
```

When I Click The Button The Array values is clear. 
So I wanna know How to save Array in View State? And Retrieve That in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
ViewState["some_key"] = roomno;

roomno = ViewState["some_key"] as string[];
```

or words to that effect :)

Comment: I tried this but,.. Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) Error is Coming in roomno = ViewState["some_key"];. how to cast?

Comment: I know only Convert.Tostring. Thanks.

Comment: see the 'as string[]' bit i added to the answer. that is bascially casting to viewstate 'object' to a 'string []', but if the object isn't castable to a 'string []' then you will et a null value rather than an InvalidCastException. So, you may have to do a null check in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewState["SomeKey"] = (string[])roomno;
roomno = (string[])ViewState["SomeKey"];
```

Or to initialize

```
string[] roomno = string[0]; 
ViewState.Add("SomeKey", roomno);
```